# Validating unique project names in Ruby on Rails for a single user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validates-uniqueness-of

In my model class `Project`, I wish to create projects with a `name`. I validate the name like this:

```
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true
```

I would like the `name` for the projects to be unique, only in the scope of a `User`. Meaning, a user cannot have multiple projects with the same name, but the projects table may contain multiple projects with the same name, owned by different users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

see [uniqueness with scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness)

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => {:scope => :user_id}
```